# Listen to messageAdded with Twilio in a Vue.js App

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, twilio

I'm working on setting up a chat service using Twilio in my Vue.js application. Sending and receiving messages works, but I am failing to pick up the messages that are added to the channel from the other chat users using the `messageAdded` listener.

My best guess is that my problem has to do with how I reference the channel in `setupChatClient` function.

```js
setAuthenticated(userData) {
  var params = {}
  this.bound.uuid = this.uuid

  this.$http.post('api/token', this.bound).then(
    response => {
      this.token = response.data.token
      this.conversationSID = response.data.conversationSid
      Chat.Client.create(response.data.token).then(client => {
        // global Client
        Client = client

        client
          .getChannelBySid(response.data.conversationSid)
          .catch(err => {
            if (err.body.code === 50300) {
              client
                .createChannel({
                  uniqueName: this.uuid,
                })
                .then(channel => {
                  // set global
                  chatChannel = channel
                  channel.join()
                  this.setupChatClient(channel)
                })
            } else {
              this.handleError(error)
            }
          })
          .then(channel => {
            // set global
            chatChannel = channel
            channel.decline()
            channel.join()
          })
          .then(channel => {
            this.setupChatClient(channel)
          })
      })
    },
    response => {
      //
    },
  )
},
```

And then to setup the channel and listen to events:

```js
setupChatClient(channel) {
  const VueThis = this
  try {
    let messages = channel.getMessages()
    if (messages.length > 0) {
      // this never gets hit.
      console.log(messages)
      VueThis.messages = messages.items
    }
    channel.on('messageAdded', message => {
      // This never gets hit
      console.log('in listner')
      var x = {}
      x.type = message.type
      x.author = message.author
      x.data = { text: message.body }
      VueThis.messages.push(x)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

  let params = {
    uuid: this.uuid,
    conversationSID: this.conversationSID,
  }

  try {
    // this does get hit.
    this.$http.post('api/tasks', params)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[`channel.getMessages` is an asynchronous method that returns a Promise](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.2.4/docs/Channel.html#getMessages__anchor) but you are using it like a synchronous method in your code which is why

```
if (messages.length > 0) {
  // this never gets hit.
  console.log(messages)
  VueThis.messages = messages.items
}
```

doesn't get hit. In this case `messages` is an unfulfilled Promise object and `messages.length` is `undefined` which apparently doesn't throw when you compare with `0`.

On the other hand, listening for the [`messageAdded` event](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.2.4/docs/Channel.html#event:messageAdded__anchor) looks correct, so I don't know what's going on there. I'd start by fixing the asynchronous event and see if that helps. To do so, use `.then` and `.catch` instead of `try` and `catch` like this:

```
setupChatClient(channel) {
  const VueThis = this
  channel.getMessages()
    .then(messagePage => {
      console.log(messagePage.items);
      VueThis.messages = messagePage.items;
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

  channel.on('messageAdded', message => {
    // This never gets hit
    console.log('in listner')
    var x = {}
    x.type = message.type
    x.author = message.author
    x.data = { text: message.body }
    VueThis.messages.push(x)
  });

  // ... rest of function
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, this did help.   I am using the new conversations api too, which was leading to my bigger problem; I was joining two channels.     Thanks again, I've got it now.

Comment: Good news you got it sorted! And you’re beyond me if you’re using channels too!